# jProfiler Live Memory All object view

Tags: object, memory, jprofiler

I have created following simple program just to observe the object and memory information when I create list of String in java.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> strObj = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            strObj.add("abc");
        }
    }
}
```

But jProfiler shows me following information in Live Memory -> All Object view which I am not able to understand.

How so many char[] instance are created? I have created only 1000 String object, how around 9000 were created?

Kindly help me out interpreting this profiler information.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic memory views cannot answer this question. You have to go to the heap walker and select all `char[]` instances. Then look at the "Cumulated incoming references" view to analyze how the instances are referenced.

You can also switch on allocation recording at startup with an appropriate recording profile, then you can see where they were allocated.

Comment: Thanks.. is it possible to view other way round - directly see  all the objects that are created with in scope of certain class e.g. in my case Main  class ?

Comment: Yes, that's even possible in the dynamic views, the allocation views show that information.

Comment: Could you please give me some details? I am really new to this tool and not familiar with these terms allocation views etc. It tool me a while to even search for Cumulated incoming references ;)

Comment: Try the view Live Memory->Allocation call tree, it should be self-explanatory,